# Change the color model of an included pdf

Tags: graphics, pdftex, color

Say I have a pdf file `foo.pdf` that I want to include in my `bla.tex` document *via* `\includegraphics{foo.pdf}`. Say that `foo.pdf` is a colored document and that I need `bla.pdf` to be in gray levels. How can I do?

Comment: What about using Ghostscript as external tool: gs -sOutputFile=output-filename -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 input-filename < /dev/null

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather rely on pdftex (no external tool). BTW, your command output an error `Error: /undefinedfilename in (sDEVICE=pdfwrite)`.

Comment: @cjorssen: The option starts with a hyphen: `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. @susis strolch Would you mind turn you comment into an anwer as it seems to be the right way to do what I ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use external tools like Ghostscript:

```
gs -sOutputFile=output-filename -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 input-filename < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

pdftex can not change the colour model of included pdfs; you have to use external tools. This (manipulate the internals of included pdfs) *might* be theoretically possible with LuaTeX, but I strongly advise against it.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask you why you advise against it?

Comment: @cjorssen: _How_ would you change the colour model of included pdfs? You'd probably have to rewrite the complete content stream. There be dragons...