# Convert color SVG / PDF to greyscale, using hatching patterns

Tags: graphics, color, svg

I have a couple of charts which are in PDF or SVG format. I want to embed them as figures, but I want to replace colors with different types of hatching patterns. Is it possible to do this with LaTeX?

If not, is anyone aware of an SVG → SVG or PDF → PDF conversion tool which can do this replacement? Unfortunately, Inkscape is totally unusable when it comes to patterns.

Note that I do not want to convert the figures to bitmaps, they should remain in vector graphics format.

Comment: Replacing the colors with different hatching patterns is not possible, but you can make a grayscale out of your pdf as shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139480/change-the-color-model-of-an-included-pdf/139493#139493